# Cannot show data from Array list to Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an application in which i need to fetch all the contacts from the contact book and display. i want the user to select some contacts and add them in a group which is saved in db.

i have created a custom list view- contactitem.xml-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


 <TextView

    android:id="@+id/contactname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"        
   android:singleLine="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/White"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/add_contacts"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have a SelectContact class for fetching contacts from Contact book-

```
   public class SelectContacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private String groupName;
    private Button back;
    private Button home;
    private List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    private ListView contactList;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.selectcontacts);

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            groupName=bundle.getString("groupName");

            back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
            back.setOnClickListener(this);

            home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home_button);
            home.setOnClickListener(this);

            contactList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();



            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            cur.moveToFirst();

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

                do{

                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    String[] fields={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};    

                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, fields, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                    pCur.moveToFirst();

                     do { 

                        String number=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        Contact c=new Contact(name,number);

                        list.add(c);

                        }while (pCur.moveToNext());

                        pCur.close();
                    }               



                   }while (cur.moveToNext());

                ContactAdapter contactAdapter=new ContactAdapter(this, R.layout.contactitem, list, contactList,groupName);



                contactList.setAdapter(contactAdapter);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent= new Intent();

            if(v==back){

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("groupName", groupName);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                intent.setClass(SelectContacts.this, GroupDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            if(v==home){
                intent.setClass(SelectContacts.this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
}
```

and implemented a custom adapter- ContactAdapter-`

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Contact>>{

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Contact>> items;

private LayoutInflater mInflater ; 

public ContactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Contact>> items) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

        this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            ViewHolder holder;

       if(convertView==null){

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactitem, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactname);

            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactnum);

            holder.add=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

       else{

            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

       String name=items.get(position).get(""+position).getContactName();

       String number=items.get(position).get(""+position).getContactNum();

       holder.name.setText(name);

       holder.number.setText(number);

        return convertView;
}



static class ViewHolder{

    TextView name;

    TextView number;

    Button add;

}
```

}

```
here Contact is a simple POJO-



public class Contact {
    private String contactName;
    private String contactNum;

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactNum() {
        return contactNum;
    }
    public void setContactNum(String contactNum) {
        this.contactNum = contactName;
    }

}
```

i am a newbie in android..

The above code works quiet fine on emulater and fetch contact name and numbers to display in list. but when i test this code on phone which have a Gmail account syncronized, it got crashed with  following error..

CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

I don't have any idea why this is happening. Please give some suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to call `cur.moveToFirst();` after fetching the Contact Cursor. After this line,

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

You are also missing the same thing here, after this - `pCur.moveToFirst();`

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
```

Comment: Made the change but Still getting the same log entry... :(

Comment: You are missing the same thing in another cursor also, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following functions:

- `cur.moveToFirst();`
- `pCur.moveToFirst();`

Comment: It worked.. thank you sir.. But still it couldnt display contacts in activity.. May be i am having some problem with my adapter...